# Indentation Error : unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation

When I compile the Python code below, I get IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

```
Files = os.listdir(".")
monthNum = 1
totMonths = 0
for year in range(2003, 2016):
    os.chdir('./'+str(year))
    for month in range(1, 13):
        totMonths = totMonths +1
        if (month < 10):
            monthStr = str(year)+"0"+str(month)
        else:
            monthStr = str(year)+str(month)
```

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: Your code ran fine for me on both [tag:python-2.x] and [tag:python-3.x]

Comment: There is a tab under `for month in range`... Just use four spaces

Comment: @cricket_007 I made a python script to fix this issue automatically: https://github.com/NoahCristino/Python-Format-Fixer

Comment: @NoahCristino Cool. I always use a text editor with soft tabs, so I don't have that issue

Comment: You mix tabs and spaces. The second `for` has idented with 4 spaces, the rest of the code use tabs. Use always 4 spaces to indent (PEP8) .

Comment: @cricket_007 Which editor?

Comment: @NoahCristino Vim, Atom, PyCharm. Anything but notepad, really

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh. I use notepad++. It's more convenient, since you can just right click, and open with notepad++

Comment: @NoahCristino I can also right click and use the options I listed

Comment: @cricket_007 oh

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused when the actual indentation does not match the expected indentation -- a likely culprit is tabs v spaces, and indentation consistency.

For example, the following code would throw this error:

```
if true:
    return 1
if false:
     return 2
```

Note that while the `true` statement is indented by 4 spaces, the `false` statement is indented by five.

This example would also throw this error, and depending on your text editor could be invisible (hidden chars added for reference):

```
if true:
....return 1
if false:
⇥   return 2
```

In this case the `true` statement is indented using four space characters, while the `false` statement is indented using a tab symbol.

Along with the IndendtationError you provided, it should give you the exact line the error is occuring on. That said, the sample you provided is small enough that unindenting & reindenting the whole thing should resolve it.

Comment: The error is also caused by mixing tabs and spaces

Comment: Edited to include that information